# Why does the following invocation of "substring" fail?

Tags: java

```
class strb1
{
    static public void main(String a_[])
    {  
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Test");
         StringBuilder sb1;
         sb1 = sb.append("ing").append("a").substring(0); //Line 1
         System.out.println(sb);
         System.out.println(sb1); 
    }   
}
```

This program gives me compiler error at line 1. `substring` is a valid method in the StringBuilder class so I am not sure what I am missing here. Can someone point me out whats wrong?

Comment: Out of curiosity: how can the 9th line be "Line 1"? ;-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#substring%28int%29) is indeed a valid method - but it returns a `String` reference, not a `StringBuilder`, so you can't assign the return value to `sb1`. This should work:

```
String x = sb.append("ing").append("a").substring(0);
```

However, you should *also* take a step back, and look at the error message again. Make sure you understand every part of it, and ask yourself why that wasn't enough information to diagnose the issue yourself. This sort of self-evaluation should help you diagnose future problems without consulting the community. (I'm sure many people are happy to help, but it's more efficient for everyone if you can work it out yourself.)

One helpful technique here is to reduce the scope of the issue as far as possible - so I'd probably have isolated it to a single method call first:

```
sb.append("ing").append("a");
sb1 = sb.substring(0);
```

At that point, when the second line flags up an error, there's less to consider. The error would be something like:

```
Test.java:11: error: incompatible types
    sb1 = sb.substring(0);
                      ^
  required: StringBuilder
  found:    String
1 error
```

Now admittedly that's not the clearest error message in the world, but given that there is *no* other use of `String` in that statement, it *has* to be the return value of the method - whose documentation you should also check as a matter of course, too.

Comment: Totally beat you by 5 seconds :D

Comment: Thanks Jon and I will try to follow what you have advised :)

Answer (score 5):

`substring(0)` returns a `String` and you are trying to assign it to a `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 1):

[`StringBuilder#substring(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#substring%28int%29) is declared as:

```
public String substring(int start)
```

not as StringBuilder. You need to create a new StringBuilder from the String you get or change the type of sb1 to String, in which case I'd rename it as well for clarity, as a string called `sb` could be assumed to be a `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 1):

`substring` returns `String` but you are trying to store it in `StringBuilder`

Answer (score 0):

**Additions:**

you can also use `new StringBuilder()`

```
sb1=new StringBuilder(sb.append("ing").append("a").substring(0)); // Line 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
sb1 = sb.append("ing").append("a").substring(0);
```

with

```
sb1 = sb.append("ing").append("a");
```